# Is it recommended to use the Spring's predefined InitializingBean and DisposableBean callbacks or not?

Tags: java, spring

Is it recommended to use the Spring's predefined `InitializingBean` and `DisposableBean` callbacks or own `init-method` and `destroy-method` for `initialization` and `cleanup`.

I just started learning **Spring Framework** and I confused with the follwing statements that,

1. It is recommended that you **do not use** the InitializingBean or DisposableBean callbacks, because XML configuration gives much flexibility in terms of naming your method. (From a Tutorial Blog)
2. It is recommended to **use** Spring's predefined InitializingBean or DisposableBean callbacks. (From my Tutor)

Are both valid based on the scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one doesn't force your class to implement a Spring-proprietary interface, but recommends using XML to configure your beans. XML is, quite frankly, awful, and Spring has provided Java configurations or simple annotations for a long time, that allows removing the need for verbose, cumbersome, unsafe XML configuration.

I would simply use standard [PostConstruct and PreDestroy annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) for this.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is just a matter of choice on how much you want to be "intruded" by Spring.

Personally, I use those Spring callback interfaces for Spring-related classes, for example, factory beans, aspects, bean post-processors, etc.

For things that should be neutral to container, I would rather having my own methods for initialization etc.

That means, I prefer a mixture of both.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is pretty clearly explained in the Spring documentation.

> The JSR-250 @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy annotations are generally
>   considered best practice for receiving lifecycle callbacks in a modern
>   Spring application. Using these annotations means that your beans are
>   not coupled to Spring specific interfaces. For details see Section
>   5.9.7, “@PostConstruct and @PreDestroy”.
>
> If you don’t want to use the JSR-250 annotations but you are still
>   looking to remove coupling consider the use of init-method and
>   destroy-method object definition metadata.